# Re-uploading a file after passing them into AWS lambdas(nodejs) + API gateway

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, file-upload

I have a REST API created using AWS Lambdas and API gateway.

This API accommodates file uploads and I have a requirement to parse the uploaded files and then send those files individual to another source as form data.

When I send two images via postman and log the event body I get the following string. *(It has two files)*

[image: postman request]

```
----------------------------269453880547064499146449
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="smiling.png"
Content-Type: image/png

�PNG


IHDR��asBIT|d�^IDAT8���=KBa��IB����"�-P\�6!Bz�D�c�hk�K�hAV`Km���K�PKm��Oý�R�-�O��<�#ZkzT���4B��nMȑ0����@#�A�- ����7w��"�fY��J�C�)�Z`D3�a��E�h���<F�7w����d�ɉ7���Y�?f�+Y�&9�B����P����`%�d:�T
�m�h�K�`����zT;�e �mc�$=A�q���&@Y��4O=W����P@�T���*��V�t`a��H�UD��6��Һ���W[��,  ��u�Ea�.c�-��S�z���Q�`���S�~y��xݡ�O�]IEND�B`�
----------------------------269453880547064499146449
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="smiling.png"
Content-Type: image/png

�PNG


IHDR��asBIT|d�^IDAT8���=KBa��IB����"�-P\�6!Bz�D�c�hk�K�hAV`Km���K�PKm��Oý�R�-�O��<�#ZkzT���4B��nMȑ0����@#�A�- ����7w��"�fY��J�C�)�Z`D3�a��E�h���<F�7w����d�ɉ7���Y�?f�+Y�&9�B����P����`%�d:�T
�m�h�K�`����zT;�e �mc�$=A�q���&@Y��4O=W����P@�T���*��V�t`a��H�UD��6��Һ���W[��,  ��u�Ea�.c�-��S�z���Q�`���S�~y��xݡ�O�]IEND�B`�
----------------------------269453880547064499146449--
```

I used `lambda-multipart-parser` to parse this body and extract the meta data.

```
import parser from 'lambda-multipart-parser'

....

const result = await parser.parse(event)
```

The result above gives the files with the following type.

```
   {
        filename: string
        content: Buffer
        contentType: string
        encoding: string
        fieldname: string
    }
```

The issue I have is that I have to send these files individually to another server as `multipart/formdata`.

Approaches I've tried so far.

**Approach 1**

Used regex to split the event body by the boundary the web boundary in the example is `----------------------------269453880547064499146449`.

```
 const splitFileBody = event.body?.split(fileBoundary)
```

After splitting it I am left with a string.

```
// In this example I am only trying to send one file

formData.append('file', splitFileBody[0])
```

Outcome : The above approach gives me me a 400 HTTP status code along with the following error

> body of your POST request is not well-formed multipart/form-data

**Approach 2**

Tried creating an object of type `File` in lambda using the parsed file as follows

```
    const fileC = new File([file.content], file.fieldname, { type: file.contentType, lastModified: Number(new Date()) })
    console.log('fileC', fileC)
    const formData = new FormData()
    formData.append('file', fileC)
```

Outcome : Lambda logs give `File is not defined` error.

**Approach 3**

Passed in the parsed information into `form.append` directly without `new File`

```
form.append('file', file.content, {
    filename: file.filename,
    contentType: file.contentType
  });
```

Outcome: The above approach gives me me a 400 HTTP status code along with the following error

> body of your POST request is not well-formed multipart/form-data

Are my approaches correct. If not what should I do differently. If the approaches above are fine, which of them is better and how to I avoid the errors?

**Additional Info**

- I am using `form-data` package because I kept on getting `FormData is not defined during the lambda runtime`.

```
import FormData from 'form-data'

....

formData.append('file', file.content, {
      filename: file.filename
    })
```

- I am using axios to make the post request

```
  const res = await axios.post(URL, formData, {
      headers: {
        ...formData.getHeaders(),
        'content-length': file.content.length
      }
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parsed file content can be directly appended to `formData` from `form-data` as follows

```
const result = await parser.parse(event)

const formData = new FormData();


for (const file of result.files) {

  formData.append('file', file.content, {
    filename: file.filename,
    contentType: file.contentType
  });
}
```

Additionally the `content-length` should have the the value `formData.getLengthSync()` as follows. The reason is that `formData` might contain other fields appended to it and `file.content.length` only contains the size of the file instead of including the other data appended.

```
await axios.post(URL, formData, {
  headers: {
    ...formData.getHeaders(),
    'Content-Length': formData.getLengthSync()
  }
})
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment @traynor. Doing this gives me `The body of your POST request is not well-formed multipart/form-data. `  similar to approach one. I shall update my question to include this approach as well.

Comment: can you include the code where you make the request, i.e. passing `formData`

Comment: Hi, I've updated some additional info at the bottom

Comment: try the updated code, try making the request without headers etc.

Comment: Hi traynor, I have edited your answer with improvements and the working solution

Comment: great. I thought it was the request part, you were on the right track, because if _plain_ request wouldn't work, playing with `headers` would have have been my next attempt, as per docs: https://www.npmjs.com/package/form-data#axios